# Why I am getting pytest AssertionError with pytest?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

Could you help me to understand why I am getting `AssertionError` in `pytest`with simple test below?

Here is the tested function conventer.py

```
from decimal import Decimal


TWO = Decimal(10) ** -2

def us_to_dec(odds=100):
    if odds >= 0:
        return Decimal((odds / 100) + 1).quantize(TWO)
    else:
        return Decimal((100 / odds) + 1).quantize(TWO)
```

print statement on conventer py returns expected result

```
print(us_to_dec(odds=205))
3.05
```

Here is test returning assertion error test_conventer.py

```
from surebet import converter


def test_us_to_dec():
    assert converter.us_to_dec(odds=205) == 3.05
```

Test fails with following output

```
E       AssertionError: assert Decimal('3.05') == 3.05
E        +  where Decimal('3.05') = <function us_to_dec at 0x106c99598>(odds=205)
E        +    where <function us_to_dec at 0x106c99598> = converter.us_to_dec
tests/test_converter.py:16: AssertionError
```

I am not sure why I'm getting AssertionError

EDIT:

If anyone else runs into same I ended up doing the following:

```
from pytest import approx

from decimal import Decimal

from surebet import converter

def test_us_to_dec():
    assert converter.us_to_dec(odds=205) == approx(Decimal(3.05))
```

Simply comparing `converter.us_to_dec(odds=205) == approx(3.05)` will cause `TypeError`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Decimal((205 / 100) + 1).quantize(Decimal(10) ** -2) == Decimal('3.05')
# --> True

Decimal((205 / 100) + 1).quantize(Decimal(10) ** -2) == 3.05
# --> False
```

Decimal values are not guaranteed to be equal to `float` values even if they have the same repr due to the limitations of floating point arithmatic. In this case `3.05` cannot be expressed exactly in binary, so when the two values are compared `3.05` is converted to

```
Decimal(3.05) == Decimal('3.04999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875')
```

before the comparison is made.

Comment: Ah Thanks. That makes sense. I presume pytest approximate it is then.